# Execute method when IUScrollView finishes scrolling iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrolLView control and I would like to execute a method when the user finishes scrolling. An alternative would be to use the touchesEnded delegate but I would like the method to get called when the UIScrollView finishes scrolling. If the user scrollers really fast and let go it's finger the scroller will continue to scroll and decelerate until it no longer moves. That is when I would like to call my method. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the delegate

[scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html)

Comment: r u implemented uiscrollviewdelegate...?